# The form moves when i select a date in a form. Is a CSS problem?

Tags: html, css

i have this [page](http://www.tirengarfio.com/rs2/web/index.php).

When I choose a day instead of "Dia:" in "Fecha de nacimiento" the form moves a little (at least in Firefox/Ubuntu).

Is a CSS problem?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

When the width of the `select` box changes, the width of the containing form also changes. If you set an explicit `width` on the select box, it won't happen:

```
<select id="register_fecha_nac_day" name="register[fecha_nac][day]" style="width: 4em;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Javi,

You might want to start with getting rid of the table that holds your form as there is no reason for it.

The form moves because the select box doesn't have a width defined so the width changes when the content changes.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but... why should i get rid of the table?? You mean I should replace it with another thing?

Comment: Because the form fields don't represent tabular data. html is all about the meaning of the content. Your form doesn't represent a table: you are using a table for styling purposes. 

See http://examples.webtypes.com/goodform/ for alternatives.

Good luck.